# Copy Calendar Processing from One Calendar to another in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Using the newest Exchange Online Powershell module I'd like to be able to copy the calendar processing rules from one calendar to another.

I used:
`Get-CalendarProcessing "<Calendar UPN>" |FL`

And found all the attributes for two Calendars and realised there were a number of attributes that differed between them and would like to know if there's a way I can copy the attributes of one calendar to another without manually putting every attribute change into one powershell command. (For example: `Set-CalendarProcessing "<Calendar UPN>" -EnforceCapacity True -MaximumConflictInstances 5` - etc... etc...)

Am I able to export attributes from one and then set them on the other using a CSV file somehow?

[Edit]

Managed to get the CSV exported with the below:

`Get-CalendarProcessing "<UPN>" |Export-CSV -path C:\Temp\Processes.csv`

Comment: You could do a `Get-CalendarProcessing` for both UPN's, then loop over the attributes you find interesting and if the target upn differs from the source upn's attribs, build a [splatting Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) using the source attribs. Then use that Hashtable to Set-CalendarProcessing on the target.

Comment: Hi @Theo, thanks for the comment, this seems advanced for the level of Powershell experience I have is very limited. Could you possibly explain a bit further on how I could do that? I am not familiar with that syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, you could do something like this

```
$sourceCalendar = "<Source Calendar UPN>"
$targetCalendar = "<Target Calendar UPN>"

# create an array of attributes of interest to copy from source to target
$attribsToCopy = 'EnforceCapacity', 'MaximumConflictInstances', 'AllowConflicts', 
                 'EnableResponseDetails', 'ForwardRequestsToDelegates', 'ProcessExternalMeetingMessages'

# get the settings from both the source and the target
$sourceSettings = Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity $sourceCalendar
$targetSettings = Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity $targetCalendar

# create a Hashtable for splatting the appropriate attributes to Set-CalendarProcessing
$params = @{}
foreach ($attribute in $attribsToCopy) {
    if ($sourceSettings.$attribute -ne $targetSettings.$attribute) {
    $params[$attribute] = $sourceSettings.$attribute
}
# if there are changes listed in the Hashtable
if ($params.Count) {
    $params['Identity'] = $targetCalendar
    Set-CalendarProcessing @params
    Write-Host "Attributes copied to Calendar $targetCalendar"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Calendar $targetCalendar did not need updating"
}
```